# Border-radius & padding not working in IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have used bellow css for image.

```
.single_comitment img {
    background: #eee none repeat scroll 0 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 500px;
       -moz-border-radius: 500px;
            border-radius: 500px;
    left: 5%;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    top: 70px;
}
```

But image border radius perfectly not working in IE11.

Comment: Could you please make an example showing the issue ? You can use the [Free Client-Side Code Editor "JSFiddle"](https://jsfiddle.net/) to give us some code in order to identify the problem.

Comment: looks like it work's fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/rzubxkem/ what are you not seeing?/expecting to see?

Comment: @atmd in ie11, if you have a proper image that appears, it will make the image square: http://jsfiddle.net/rzubxkem/1/

Comment: square? is that a typo?

Comment: @atmd nope, perhaps this will show it better: http://jsfiddle.net/rzubxkem/6/ - square image in ie11, round image in chrome

Comment: Right I see, my mistake. thanks for the fiddle

Comment: IE11 requires the `border-style` to be set to something in order for it to work, it's same with trying to use border-image, it won't work in IE without `border-style` but will work fine in everything else. Adding it makes the image round instead of square.

Comment: You can get around it by having `border:1px transparent; border-style:solid;` as you're right, having 'hidden' brings the bug back.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `background-color` and `padding`, why not use `border`:

```css
    .single_comitment img {
        border: 10px solid #eee;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 500px;
        -moz-border-radius: 500px;
        border-radius: 500px;
        left: 5%;
        position: relative;
        top: 70px;
        overflow:hidden
    }
```

```html
<div class="single_comitment">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/800/city/1/">
</div>
```